# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when trying to update global variable

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have the following code in a method ( Utils.currentPrinters is a static JsonObject ):

```
    JsonObject printers = Utils.currentPrinters;

    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : Utils.currentPrinters.entrySet()) {

        String key = entry.getKey();

        JsonObject printer = (JsonObject) entry.getValue();

        if (...) {
            printers.remove(key);
        }
    }

    Utils.currentPrinters = printers;
```

There are two threads that actually call this method. If it's only one, there are no problems at all. But after running few seconds with two threads, it crashes with the following Exception:

```
 05-13 12:01:43.168    5739-5739/com.wasp.pos.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap$LinkedTreeMapIterator.nextNode(LinkedTreeMap.java:541)
        at com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap$EntrySet$1.next(LinkedTreeMap.java:565)
        at com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap$EntrySet$1.next(LinkedTreeMap.java:563)
        at com.wasp.pos.app.server.PrintersFinder.clearPrinters(PrintersFinder.java:184)
        at com.wasp.pos.app.server.PrintersFinder.access$000(PrintersFinder.java:30)
        at com.wasp.pos.app.server.PrintersFinder$1UpdateListThread.run(PrintersFinder.java:124)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I could not really find anything that fixes this, ConcurrentMap or synchronized (printers) did not fixed it. Please, help.

Comment: Exactly how did you use synchronize? Did you make the methods synchronized?

Comment: Even with just one, it looks like you're modifying a collection that you're iterating over, which is a bad idea...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated, do not remove from a collection you are iterating over. Instead:

```
Set<String> removed = new TreeSet<String>();
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : Utils.currentPrinters.entrySet()) {

    String key = entry.getKey();

    JsonObject printer = (JsonObject) entry.getValue();

    if (...) {
        removed.add(key);
    }
}
for (String key : removed)
    Utils.currentPrinters.remove(key);
```

Two other things:

- The temporary variable "printers" in your original code changes nothing since it references the same object. Unless of course for some reason the code is clearer to you that way...
- If this method is accessed by multpile threads... Don't! They are doing the same thing and you will gain nothing from it. Synchronize the whole block.

Comment: Thank you. That did it. I thought I was modifying a different object ... but it was the same actually.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot remove (`printers.remove(key);`) items from a collection while you are iterating (`for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : Utils.currentPrinters.entrySet())`) over them.

The best way to achieve your aim is to collect a list of all items you want to remove and remove them at the end.

```
    List<String> remove = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : Utils.currentPrinters.entrySet()) {

        String key = entry.getKey();

        if (...) {
            remove.add(key);
        }
    }
    // Remove the ones I don't want.
    for(String r:remove) {
        printers.remove(r);
    }
```

Once you've done that you still need to either use `synchronized` or a `ConcurrentMap`.

Comment: Oops, I've got pretty much a duplicate answer, sorry! I had not seen the update with code when I posted. Although, I might point out that _map_ doesn't exist in your code :)

Comment: @schmop - Cute that we're almost identical - I prefer your use of a `Set` but you've dropped the `.entrySet()` from `currentPrinters` and you've dropped the `{}` from your final remove loop. Good call on the `map`.

Comment: Ha, you're right! While we're at it, using a list like you do makes more sense and is faster since unicity of the keys is already guaranteed by the map.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you using [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), it will allow you to remove the objects while iterating over the list without throwing ConcurrentModification exception.

Comment: Except the remove method is optional, better to play it safe!